# 700D Rebel T5i - View Photos on TV instantly and wireless

Tags: canon, wireless, canon-700d, slideshow

I have a Canon 700D (aka Rebel T5i) and will do some shooting on a birthday. Is there a possibility to connect my camera to a TV and make an instant slide show of all the pictures I have taken? Preferably, any wireless connection to the TV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all covered on pages 258-265 of your [*700D Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300010890/05/EOS_700D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf). You may use either the supplied standard A/V cable or an optional HDMI cable for high resolution playback. The only way to do it wirelessly would be to use an Eye-Fi card to transfer the images to another device (pp. 311-13 of the *Instruction Manual*) as they are shot and then play back the images using the other device.